# Exclude a route for production using React Router within Create React App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm using React Router inside Create React App to handle my apps navigation. Along with my pages, I also have a route used only for development to display styles (`/styles`). I'd like to exclude this route when the build command runs so it's removed in production.

I'm currently thinking of checking an environment variable but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `process` variable for that.

If you wrap that router with `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`, this will become false during building and this route will be excluded, since `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `production` and static false statements will be removed.

```
{process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && <Route ... />}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).

Comment: Isn't NODE_ENV considered an environment variable?

Comment: This was along the lines I was thinking but I was only looking at documentation for React Router and CRA so thank you for this.