# Restrict React route for the development only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, routes

Is there a chance I can restrict the React route, to work only in the development mode, and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an environment variable for this, for example `NODE_ENV`.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Personally I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env so environment variables work the same way on all platforms. Then you can define a start:dev parameter under scripts in your package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js"
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js"
  }
```

And then conditionally run code with

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
```

Comment: So how do I then restrict the route for the development mode? =(

Comment: Up to you, lots of solutions. Maybe don't include the route through an if-statement. Or navigate the user back to the homepage if you are in production, and someone is trying to navigate to the restricted route.

Comment: Here's how to restrict the route for the development mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880923/733092